# fabric 1.3.9 to 1.4

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a specific problem with the version changes. I use the fabric canvas to draw objects on it. In addition I created another canvas that acts like a magnifying glass to get more details out the background of the fabric canvas, this all works.

My problem is that each of the created objects on the canvas can also be deleted by the user, therefore I did something similar as the demo "**interaction with objects outside the canvas**".

In **1.3.9** this all works fine and the user can click on a f.e. delete button next to the object and it is deleted.

In **1.4.0** if the user clicks the button... it creates a new object. It seems there is another event binding. Does anybody know what this could be? Any help is very much appreciated.

I have to go with 1.4.0 as in the previous version setting images as background does not work (it is always stretched to the whole canvas without keeping ratio)

Anybody have a similar issue? It is very important for me that this kind of functionality does work.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create small jsfiddle testcase?!

Comment: hey. yes i will try to make a fiddle. the thing is that i created a application using phone gap and jsfabric to to some image manipulation. hopefully if i do it without the phone gap i can recreate the problem. thx

Comment: hey. i tried to create a fiddle but it makes no sense as it is not simple possible to reproduce it in an different environment. but i have a question depending on the external buttons in fabric. i think i know what the problem is. if i create a external button to my object and i click on it... the target object is "undefined". but it shouldn't be. it should be the "class" of the selected object or as it is part of the actual selected object? does it make sense? thx in advance